# Linux UDP ephemeral port bind occasionally fails to receive

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, udp

I am writing a set of tests that depend on two applications communicating (locally) with a UDP socket. These UDP sockets are originally bound using port 0, then the actual bound port is queried using getsockname and shared between the two applications.  Occasionally, the subsequent recv calls fail to return any data without any error reporting during binding etc.

I've simplified my implementation to a bare-bones test an included it below.  It fails with "Received failed, got -1 expeccted 6" about 1 of 10 runs. What am I missing in the socket setup to reliable use an ephemeral, OS-assigned port?

````
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <cstring>
#include <thread>

int32_t createSocket(uint16_t& rBoundPort)
{
  int32_t s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

  if (s >= 0)
  {
    timeval timeout; 
    timeout.tv_sec = 1;
    timeout.tv_usec = 0;
    
    if (setsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, &timeout, sizeof(timeval)) < 0)
    { 
      ::close(s);
      return -1;
    }

    int32_t r(1);
    if (setsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &r, sizeof(int)) < 0)
    { 
      close(s);
      return -1;
    }

    int32_t bufSize(50000);
    if (setsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, &bufSize, sizeof(bufSize)) < 0)
    { 
      close(s);
      return -1;
    }

    // Setup local listening port
    sockaddr_in listenAddress;
    memset(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&listenAddress), 0, sizeof(listenAddress));
    listenAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;
    inet_aton("127.0.0.1", &listenAddress.sin_addr);
    listenAddress.sin_port = htons(0);
    
    if (bind(s, (struct sockaddr*)&listenAddress,  sizeof(listenAddress)) != 0)
    { 
      close(s);
      return -1;
    }

    // Update the bound listen port
    socklen_t boundAddrLen = sizeof(sockaddr_in);
    getsockname(s, (struct sockaddr*)&listenAddress, &boundAddrLen);
    rBoundPort = ntohs(listenAddress.sin_port);
  }

  return s;
}

void mysockettest(int32_t s, uint16_t destPort)
{
  const int32_t dataSize = 6;
  char aWrite[dataSize] = { 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05 };
  char aRx[dataSize];

  sockaddr_in dest;
  memset((char*)&dest, 0, sizeof(dest));
  dest.sin_family = AF_INET;
  inet_aton("127.0.0.1", &dest.sin_addr);
  dest.sin_port = htons(destPort);

  sendto(s, aWrite, dataSize, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&dest, sizeof(sockaddr_in));

  sockaddr_in src;
  socklen_t srcSize = sizeof(sockaddr_in);
  memset((char*)&src, 0, srcSize);

  int32_t bytesReceived = recvfrom(s, aRx, dataSize, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&src, &srcSize);
  if (bytesReceived != dataSize)
  {
    printf("Received failed, got %d expected %d\n", bytesReceived, dataSize);
  }
}

int main(int argc, char** pargv)
{
  uint16_t s1Port(0);
  int32_t s1 = createSocket(s1Port);
  if (s1 < 0)
  {
    printf("FAILED TO OPEN SOCKET 1\n");
    return -1;
  }
  if (s1Port < 1)
  {
    printf("FAILED TO BIND SOCKET 1 TO PORT\n");
    return -1;
  }

  uint16_t s2Port(0);
  int32_t s2 = createSocket(s2Port);
  if (s2 < 0)
  {
    printf("FAILED TOOPEN SOCKE 2\n");
  }
  if (s2Port < 1)
  {
    printf("FAILED TO BIND SOCKET 2 TO PORT\n");
  }

  std::thread t1(mysockettest, s1, s2Port);
  std::thread t2(mysockettest, s2, s1Port);

  t1.join();
  t2.join();

  close(s1);
  close(s2);
}
```
````

Comment: Should `m_listenAddress` be `boundAddr` in the call to `getsockname()`?

Comment: that was an old mistake that has since been resolved, thanks for pointing it out again. I've updated the post to show the correction implementation. But no, m_listenAddress is the correct struct instance - boundAddr was a relic left-behind.

Comment: You say the test "fails" without describing how it fails. Does it hit the timeout? Does it get the wrong data?

Comment: The socket read timeouts are hit (set at 1 second), and no data is received.  Receive data size is 0.

Comment: It's possible to have two UDP sockets bound to the same port and different local addresses; when incoming data is delivered the socket bound to a specific address will take precedence over the one bound using INADDR_ANY.

Comment: Are you suggesting that instead of INADDR_ANY, I should specify the local IP address (e.g. 127.0.0.1)? I have tried that as well without any change in the result.

Comment: Note that I have also attempted to disable SO_REUSEADDR without any effect

Comment: The only other problem I see is `m_listenAddress.sin_port = m_listenPort;` not using `htons()`, compare to `m_listenPort = ntohs(m_listenAddress.sin_port);`  You might want to confirm that between `getBoundPort()`, `updateDestination()`, and `sendto()` which I assume your `UdpComm::write()` uses, that there's exactly one `htons()` somewhere in the sequence.

Comment: @T.Waters What does `UdpComm::updateDestination()` and `UdpCom::read()` look like? You mention `recv()`, but you can't use `recv()` in UDP without a `connect()`, otherwise you would have to use `recvfrom()` instead. But you also say that the read "occasionally" fails, does that mean it "sometimes" succeeds?

Comment: You do know that UDP datagrams can get lost anywhere for any reason? If you need reliability use TCP.

Comment: @BenVoigt You found another old typo. Correcting the code. But my implementation has the correct htons conversion.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I updaed to add the additional methods. I currently have it as recv(), but it was previously recvfrom(...) with the same effect

Comment: @user207421 yes I am aware that UDP can be lossy. Though, I've never seen it when using UDP for IPC like this when it is all local.  And certainly not at these error rates (losing ~10% of my packets with this unit test and setup)

Comment: @RemyLebeau it works for about 90% of packets.

Comment: Did you run WireShark on this yet? That'd tell you if the problem lies on the sending side (packet isn't visible in WireShark) or on the receiving side (packet is visible but gets lost anyway).

Comment: Try setting a large `SO_RCVBUF` size, like 48K, maybe even much more.

Comment: All - I have re-written the sample source to be simplified and 100% complete/compilable. Note that the read times out about 1/10 runs.

Comment: Update: I did end up hooking up wireshark and saw that the SEND is not occurring. After calling sendto I am now checking the return result and errno - with  failure I am getting "Operation not permitted" - still tracking down why as I do not have any firewalls running.

Answer (score 0):

Unforntunately I can't explain the details of they "why" (perhaps someone else can), but I found that adding a global mutex lock to protect the send corrected the instability on the send. The global lock isn't practical for my situation, so instead I implemeneted a simply retry loop on the send (if send() == -1, retry 10 times). While this solution is not ideal, it has proven stable.

Once that stability was resolved, I also saw occasional failures on the read side. With SO_REUSEADDR and binding with port 0 (OS-assignment), it was possible to have both sockets be assigned and bind to the same port, so I removed the SO_REUSEADDR when binding to port 0.